# What type of vector multiplication is this?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation, vectors, vector-analysis

I am supposed to show a proof on homework where and I have no idea what this expression is supposed to mean:

$(\rho \mathbf{uu})  $

where $\mathbf{u}$ is a velocity vector.

The only types of vector multiplication I have seen are dot product and cross product.   I am confident that the professor did not mean dot product, and I do not think that it's supposed to be a cross product either. The professor also claims that there is not a typographical error.

Can somebody please explain how to interpret or simply that term?

For context, the problem is:

Show that:
$\frac{\partial\rho \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} +  \nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf{uu})  = \rho\frac{D \mathbf{u}}{D t} $

The problem is written exactly how it is displayed above.

Also, the $ \rho \frac{D \mathbf{u}}{D t}$ is the material (total) derivative from fluid mechanics.

Comment: If it is a dot product, then $ \mathbf{uu} $ is a scalar, and  the divergence of a scalar field is meaningless, according to this webpage:  [link [http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32B/chap14/section5/930d31/930_31.html]

Comment: Are you sure? These sites say that $\nabla \cdot $  indicates divergence:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence

and

http://clas.sa.ucsb.edu/staff/alex/VCFAQ/GDC/GDC.htm

and

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Divergence.html

Comment: @YuriyS There is no typo in the divergence: see my answer.  In fact, interpreting $\mathbf{uu}$ as the dot product here results in a loss of the rotational symmetry for the fluid equations.

Comment: @Strants, ok, I will delete my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, $\mathbf{uu}$ represents the [dyadic product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics) $\mathbf{uu} = \mathbf{uu}^T$ (a matrix).  It is also often written as $\mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{u}$.

In coordinates, is $\mathbf{u} = [u_1, u_2, u_3]^T$, then
$$\rho\mathbf{uu} = \left[\begin{matrix} \rho u_1u_1 & \rho u_1u_2 & \rho u_1 u_3\\ \rho u_2u_1 & \rho u_2u_2 & \rho u_2 u_3\\ \rho u_3 u_1 & \rho u_3 u_2 &\rho u_3 u_3\end{matrix}\right]$$
and
$$\nabla \cdot (\rho\mathbf{uu}) = \left[\begin{matrix} \partial_1(\rho u_1u_1) + \partial_2( \rho u_1u_2) + \partial_3( \rho u_1 u_3)\\ \partial_1(\rho u_2u_1) + \partial_2( \rho u_2u_2) + \partial_3(\rho u_2 u_3)\\ \partial_1(\rho u_3 u_1) + \partial_2(\rho u_3 u_2) +\partial_3(\rho u_3 u_3)\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: (+1) thank you, I should have been more careful in checking the notation specific to hydrodynamics

Comment: Thanks dude! you're a straight up G!